# What did Teferi plan to do when Jamuraa phased back in?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

During the Phyrexian invasion, Teferi phased the continent of Jamuraa out of reality to protect it rather than fight in the war.

Centuries later, the continent phased back in during the Time Spiral block.

It occurs to me that if the invasion had been successful, the Phyrexians might have still been there when Teferi and Jamuraa returned. He would be in an even more dangerous situation than the one he left.

When Teferi implemented his phasing plan, what did he plan to do when he returned? Did he discuss it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't read the novels, but was interested in this matter as well, I went ahead and asked the Head Designer for Magic: The Gathering, [Mark Rosewater](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/183545813443/what-was-teferis-original-plan-with-the-phased-out) about this. While Mark is not responsible for the story arc of Magic: The Gathering, he is fairly knowledgeable and likes to answer all sorts of questions.

Here is what he answered:

> His original plan was to leave them forever phased out of [sic] the Phyrexians won.

I assume that it was not intended/known by Teferi that the continents would phase in again by themselves.